# Make lsof 'always' return control to command line?

Tags: bash, lsof

Sometimes you are forced to hit Ctrl-C to cancel.
with something like:

```
lsof -i :80
```

Other times it returns automatically. 
Why is that?
Is there a way to make it always return control without user interaction?

Comment: It always does, it just hasn't *finished* yet. Probably waiting on DNS.

Comment: Can run `strace` on it to see why it's hanging.

Comment: Thanks was unaware of strace - will give that a try